# How to indicate the possibility to slide

Tags: touch-screen, tablet, slideshow

I have a menu in which the user can slide between different items. Only one item is visible at a time (in green), and the user can slide left and right to display the next or previous item.

Sometimes, users don't find out that they can slide. How can I indicate that it's possible to slide to navigate between items?

[image]

It's for a tablet app, so I'm talking about touch inputs.

Comment: you can show a part of your left / right contents to indicate the swipe

Comment: Can you expand on this. Give an example?

Comment: http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/25527/best-way-to-indicate-that-a-image-gallery-can-be-swiped-left-right-on-mobile-tab/25530#25530

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Material design - Gesture education](https://material.io/guidelines/growth-communications/gesture-education.html#):

> Gesture education should happen as the user needs it. It doesn’t need to be condensed into a user’s first moments with an app. It’s smart and contextual, helping users interact with an element or surface in a way they have not done so previously.
>
> Show gesture education only to users who have not performed the gesture.

The page has great information and recommendations. I would add that you **let the user also tap the grey items to open them**, so they don't miss the action.